# How to kill a specific docker container in a single command

Tags: docker, containers, kill

i've setup a jenkins pipeline job in a groovy script....

i am trying to build the jenkins job which runs a docker command on remote server.
my jenkins is expected to connect to remote server and perform

```
       docker run -d -p 60:80 <image name>
```

so for that i have used the following groovy script in jenkins pipeline job

```
     stage ('Deploy on App Server')
     {
         def dockrun = 'docker run -d -p 60:80 <image name>'
         sshagent(['dev-servr-crdntls'])
         {
             sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx ${dockrun}" 
         }
     }
```

This scripts runs perfectly fine. Jenkins is connecting to remote server and running the docker command and app is running on port 60.

HOWEVER as this is in jenkins pipeline for CICD, next time when the Build is run job is getting failed because port 60 is already assigned. .

I want to kill the port 60 before running the docker run -d -p ......command. Any suggestions please

Comment: I am able to kill a specific container running on port 60 at terminal level but this is not working in jenkins pipeline

$ docker rm -f `docker ps | grep 60 | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: I usually do  `docker stop [container name or id]` in the terminal, have you tried that?

Comment: Hi @NaphatAmundsen thank you for your reply.  For docker stop command we  have to pass container id  in an automation script that i am not able to do

Comment: You can give the container a known name with the `docker run --name` option, and use that name in the `docker stop` and `docker rm` commands (and elsewhere) without having to look up the container ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following command to kill the running container that occupies a given port:

```sh
docker kill $(docker ps -qf expose=<port>)
```

**Explanation:**
The `docker ps` command allows to list containers and has a lot of useful options. One of them is the `-f` flag for filtering for containers based on some properties. Now you could filter for the running container that occupies `<port>` by using `-f expose=<port>`. In addition, the `-q` flag can be used to only output the container ID. This output can be used as input to the `docker kill` command.

**Edit:**
Because the command mentioned above could potentially fail with an error if no container is running on the given port, the following command can be used to circumvent this problem:

```sh
docker kill $(docker ps -qf expose=<port>) 2> /dev/null || echo 'No container running on port <port>'
```

Now, the command will either kill the container occupying `<port>` if such container exists and is running, or output *No container running on port `<port>`* (optional)

Comment: Hi bajro , thank you for your answer.  This command is giving an error 

[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker ps -qf expose=90
WARNING: Error loading config file: /var/lib/jenkins/.docker/config.json: open /var/lib/jenkins/.docker/config.json: permission denied
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx sudo docker kill 
"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
[Pipeline] }
$ ssh-agent -k

Comment: @KiranSR the `docker kill` command requires at least one argument which is either the container name or ID. The `$(docker ps -qf expose=60)` portion returns the ID of a running container that occupies port 60 on your machine. However, if no container is currently occupying port 60, the command will fail like in your case. With that said, the command expects one container to be running that occupies the given port (e.g. 60)

Comment: @KiranSR see my updated answer for an example where the potential of an error is handled

Comment: docker kill $(docker ps -qf expose=<port>) 2> /dev/null || echo 'No container running on port <port>'  this works great..... thank you so much.


Now i will check this in Jenkins pipeline

Comment: @KiranSR Glad that I could help. Please consider marking this answer as helpful. This helps in marking this question, and thread, as answered